# SQL Convert a char to boolean

Tags: mysql, sql

I have in my table one row with a char value. When the value is NULL then a false should be outputted. If the value is not NULL then a true should be outputted.

So when I try to set `user_group.tUser` to 0 or 1 then I'm getting this error:

Invalid column name 'false'.

Invalid column name 'true'.

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT name
                FROM   v_company 
                WHERE  companyId = userView.companyId), ' ') AS company, 
    userView.value                                         AS companyUser, 
    userView.display                                       AS displayedUser,
    CASE 
        WHEN user_group.tUser IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END                                             AS userIsMemberOfGroup 
FROM   v_user userView 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cr_user_group user_group
                    ON ( user_group.group = 'Administrators' 
                        AND user_group.tUser = userView.value ) 
ORDER  BY company ASC, 
        displayedUser ASC
```

Comment: Are you asking us to write a query to do that or some PHP code to do that?

Comment: Use ISNULL, just pass it the field name and it returns TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: I don't see false and true used in your query. Where is the error coming from?

Comment: @dewey . . . Your sample query cannot be generating that error because it has no references to `true` or `false` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the logic you want:

```
SELECT COALESCE(v.name, ' ') as company, 
       u.value as companyUser, u.display as displayedUser,
       (EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM cr_user_group ug
                WHERE ug.group = 'Administrators' AND
                      ug.tUser = uv.value
               ) 
       ) as userIsMemberOfGroup 
FROM v_user u LEFT JOIN
     v_company c 
     ON c.companyId = v.companyId
ORDER BY company ASC, displayedUser ASC ;
```

In general, MySQL is very flexible about going between booleans and numbers, with `0` for false and `1` for true.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL [`IF`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_if.asp) function to return `'false'` when `name IS NULL`, else `'true'`:

```
SELECT IF(name IS NULL, 'false', 'true')
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `CASE` expression would work here:

```
SELECT
    name,
    CASE WHEN name IS NOT NULL THEN true ELSE false END AS name_out
FROM yourTable;
```

We could also shorten the above a bit using `IF`:

```
IF(name IS NOT NULL, true, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN name IS NULL THEN 'false'
        ELSE 'true'
    END
FROM
    table1;
```